# Best way to learn PostgreSQL stored procedures?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there a good tutorial or something similar for learning how to write Stored Procedures (for a PostgreSQL database). I'm a definite newbie when it comes to writing Stored Procedures at all, so the clearer and simpler things are explained, the better...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You almost had it, but better start here [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)

Some will point that `PL/pgSQL` is not the only way to write Stored Procedures for PostgreSQL and they will be right (that's one of the advantages of Postgres), but on the other hand `PL/pgSQL` is nice and relatively easy to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Note that obviously, here's a good place to start:[sql-createfunction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)